# system defined by one space with solutions on another: $x∈{\mathbb{C}},y∈{\mathbb{C}} ↣(x,y)∈{\mathbb{R}^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, notation, systems-of-equations, several-complex-variables

Here is system of equations defined from one domain~codmain but presented onto another (in this case, a proper subset, the reals out of all complex numbers). Is it notated sensically and properly? The inequalities involving (moduli and absvals of) *y* and *x* should only restrict (if cause any alteration to) the range of outputs; I am wondering cases when it can add values (discrete, ranges, or both), but more importantly how fully to solve this problem (which I concocted out of self interest, and am okay with modifying per recommendation prior to an answer).

$∀[x],[y]∈{\mathbb{C}}↣ ∃[x∈{\mathbb{R}}]<y, ∀(x,y)∈{\mathbb{R}^2}:$

$|y|<|2x|$

$y=$<sup>+</sup>$\sqrt{2x+1}$

$x={(y-1)}^4-1$

Comment: Even copying your title to point out its lack of sense is a very frustrating exercise.  You wrote $\LaTeX$ mixed with text (I've simplified slightly): "$f∘([x,y]$∈all$\mathbb C^2)$ ↣ $(x,y)$∈$\mathbb R^2$".  This makes no sense.  You are doing yourself and Readers no favors by proceeding in this fashion.  Write in whole sentences.

Comment: What doesn't make sense about it? It's more succinct than stating out in sentences like this i.e. "system of equation with x and y both elements of complex numbers that become or stay reals or are omitted" or what it said previously.

Comment: That at least is a parseable noun phrase in English.  Your title is a jumble, a mishmash of improperly used symbols with the English word "all" inserted in an odd place.  The symbol $f$ does not mean "system of equations". It would often represent a function, but you have not otherwise defined the function $f$.  The symbol $\circ$ is often used to mean *composition* of two functions, but that's not how you've used it.  You have indicated what two functions we are supposed to compose. What to make of square brackets in the first pair $[x,y]$ versus parentheses in the second pair $(x,y)$? Etc.

Comment: Alright some constructive feedback.  The brackets are to indicate the domain~codamin of *x* and *y*, contrasted with the ordered-pair coordinates of their outputs. No I did not define the function as such but it still defines the parameters. How instead should it be phrased mathematically?  And what about the body of the Question?

Comment: I've deleted a couple of earlier Comments as we move on in discussing how to phrase your Question.  Of course you know some functions (like the absolute value) which assign real values to all complex numbers.  "Define $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ by $f(z) = |z|$."  So presumably you have a different problem in mind.  We can write conditions that "restrict" (like asking for $|y| \lt |2x|$) and consider whether a collection of conditions taken in *conjunction* (logical AND) could be satisfied.  If you want to "add" (rather than exclude) possible values, then you state a disjunction (logical OR).

Comment: If feasible I'd like a function or system valid in one range that both 'excludes' and 'imports' values of the variables from within that domain, such as having restriction for whole domains (e.g. [*x*],[*y*] in ${\mathbb{R}}$) and injection from the one not imaged (e.g. non-reals) such that the final solution (be it a an area, curve, intersections) is shaped orand positioned by not just the domain where it can possibly exist (${\mathbb{R}}$) but from another as well (non-${\mathbb{R}}$ ${\mathbb{C}}$). One restriction might apply to only one subset of a domain (still affecting the result).